# IIS 7 - Event ID 5 Error

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am moving my php sites from a Linux machine over to a windows machine with IIS7

I keep getting this error on three of my domains:

"Unable to create file mapping
Access is denied."

I have no idea how it origins... Can someone please come with some suggestions as to what would cause this error?

I dont even know what file mapping means in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Event ID 5 is related to ASP [Availability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364246.aspx).

You could check that ASP was allowed on your installation of IIS

In the IIS Manager, under  ISAPI and CGI Restrictions, Is ASP.net allowed?

Hope this helps

Shiraz

Comment: Hi Shiraz.. It was somewhat relatwed to what you say.. it was a php misconfiguration and some coding issues.

Comment: @Therealnapster Can you please elaborate? I am having the exact same problem. What was the php misconfiguration? How did you solve it? Thanks.